# Avoid redundant code in SQL SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I'd like to avoid my query to have some redundant code. Here is a very simple example of what id'like to do :

```
SELECT 
   p.id,
   p.NOM,
   CONCAT(p.NANE,'_2') AS CLONE ,
   (SELECT id FROM person WHERE NAME = CONCAT(p.NOM,'_2')  )

FROM person p
```

I have 2 times the same code :

```
CONCAT(PERSON.NAME,'_CLONE')
```

It is not easy to maintain (the code above is only a simple example of what I'm trying to do).

Is there a solution to get the same result with something like that (wich works in MySQL (tested with v14.14)) :

```
SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.name,
  CONCAT(p.name,'_clone') as CLONE ,
  (SELECT ID FROM person WHERE name = CLONE) AS CLONE_ID

FROM person p
```

This code does not work with Oracle 11.2.0.2.0
I am new to oracle, so I don't know what is the translation for the MySQL SQL code above :s

Could you please help me finding a good way of writing it ?

Comment: I edited the code because I forgot some semi colums.

Comment: @Satya : Both code work in Oracle for the first one and MySQL for the second one. The aim is to find if there is some person whose name is the same as the current person with a '_clone' suffix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest an inline view:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
      c.name clone_name,
      c.id clone_id
from person p
join
      (SELECT id, concat(name, '_clone') name FROM person) c
on p.name = c.name
```

Comment: Actually your code does not the same thing as mine (I don't want to concat on the clone name but on the first person name), but I have changed it a bit and it works !I have kept the jointure, and instead of doing 'FROM person p' I do 'FROM (SELECT CONCAT(...) NAME_CLONE,NAME,ID) p JOIN (SELECT ID,NAME) c ON p.NAME_CLONE = c.NAME.

I'd like to accept the answer but maybe you should edit it at the first place.

Comment: Do you mean you switched the two? Feel free to edit the answer if you can.